# How to handle 404 errors using webdriver code

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Could you please help us how to handle 404 errors using WebDriver code?

Comment: Please further explain what you want. What do you mean `handle`? How do you want it to be handled?

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided enough information, I'm assuming that you want to check if request results into 404 then raise an error or display some message.

In following code, I'm requesting for 'Search' link on 'http://www.google.com':

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'open-uri'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox

driver.get "http://www.google.com"
search_link = driver.find_element(:link, "Search").attribute("href")

io = open search_link
status = io.status

if status == ["404", "Not Found"]
    puts "Request is resulting into 404"
end
```

Let me know this is what you're looking for or not.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways (using Java), for a URL such as https://www.google.com/sdfsdsdfs :

```
String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
assertEquals(actualTitle, "Error 404 (Not Found)!!1" );
```

or

```
String pageSource = driver.getPageSource();
if ( pageSource.contains("404") ) assertTrue(true, "404 not found error." );
```